# How to simulate a browser crash with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I have a lot of tests that are being run with Jest and Puppeteer. I'm creating a new browser instance with `puppeteer.launch()` before each test, in order to avoid situations where re-using the browser results in flaky behavior. When I run all my tests together, **occasionally** the browser crashes after launching, and I can detect this by listening for the `browser.on('disconnected', ...)` event.

I'm now trying to handle that case, and re-create the browser if needed. The problem is how can I force the Chromium browser to crash, and send the same **disconnected** event? I've tried loading the page with special chrome:// URLs (see below).

Here's the simple example I'm working on:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

async function getPage(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await browser.on('disconnected', async () => {
    console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@ browser crashed @@@@@@@@@@@@@');
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});
  return page;
};

describe('Raw Puppeteer Test', () => {
  let page;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = await getPage('chrome://kill/');
  });
  afterEach(async () => {
    await page.close();
    await page.browser().close();
  });
  it('should relaunch the browser and re-run if the browser crashes', async () => {
    const el = await page.waitForSelector('h1');
    expect(el).not.toBeNull();

  });
});
```

While **kill** and **crash** do appear to crash the Chromium browser, it doesn't send the **disconnected** event that a real crash would. I also tried **inducebrowsercrashforrealz** but that just results in a net::ERR_INVALID_URL error.

Is there a way to simulate a failed browser initialization in Puppeteer, that mimics a real-life crash?

Comment: `kill` and `crash` are working on the browser tab level, you want to crash the whole browser instance itself. the official way is indeed the `chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz` debug page to do this, you need the way around the ERR_INVALID_URL error, most probably with specific [launch args](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). however, if I understand correctly: you need this only to restart the browser if it would crash, for this, you could find more robust solutions out there (e.g. [puppeteer cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster))

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with this thread on puppeteer's Github but you might find it useful: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1589